# coloring points with extremely faint alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a lot of points with extremely small alpha values in ggplot2. As I discovered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600973/extreme-alpha-scaling-unexpectedly-leads-to-completely-transparent-geoms/71601903#71601903), the smallest possible alpha value in R is around 0.003.

Weirdly, at the smallest alpha value, while the points are still rendered, there is no color to them, and only as alpha values are being increased does color slowly appear. I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
someData <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 100000),
                       y = rnorm(n = 100000))

p1 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "#fbb4ae", alpha = (1/254.99) * 1)
p2 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "#fbb4ae", alpha = (1/254.99) * 3)
p3 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "#fbb4ae", alpha = (1/254.99) * 6)
p4 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "#fbb4ae", alpha = (1/254.99) * 12)
print((p1+p2)/(p3+p4))
```

[image]

Weirdly, the plots look as expected if I use a color designation like so

```
p1 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", alpha = (1/254.99) * 1)
p2 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", alpha = (1/254.99) * 3)
p3 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", alpha = (1/254.99) * 6)
p4 <- ggplot(someData) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", alpha = (1/254.99) * 12)
print((p1+p2)/(p3+p4))
```

[image]

Comment: When I render your first example, the points stay coloured in the top-right, but the top-left plot appears empty. My guess is that this is going to be a device dependent thing how alpha blending is handled. Have you tried other devices, such as {ragg} or {Cairo} devices?

Comment: I tried `png`, `jpeg`, `pdf`, `ragg::agg_png`, `ragg::agg_jpeg`, and `ragg::agg_capture`/`plot(as.raster(.))`, and all show the top-left as blank (on my system: win11, R-4.1.2).

Comment: I tried jpg, png, tiff via Cairo but none of them work for me.

Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux @teunbrand?

Comment: I tried it with {ragg} on Windows